# Spring-batch pass data from writer or processor to a RestConroller

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch application. In my batch I read from a database. I process the data. From there I want my writer to produce a json response.

Bellow is how my writer currently looks like. Here I am writing to a file. I want to do away with that and write the output as a json response that can be accessed via a rest call.

Writer :

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends  Entity> items) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Writing the output");
    writeTofile(items);
    logger.log(Level.INFO,  "Done : Writing the output");

}

// Todo :
private void writeTofile(List<? extends  Entity> items) throws Exception{

    Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Text/Outputs/output"+now+".txt"));
    writer.write(items.toString());

    writer.close();
}
```

I want to have something like this :

```
@RestController
public class RestControler {
private List<? extends Entity> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

@GetMapping(value = "get-items")
public List<? extends Entity> getAll(){

   // Return the processed data

    return  dataList;
}
```

So another service can come and pick up the information by making a rest call.

Not sure I am thinking about it correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want my writer to produce a json response"? Where to produce this response? In a file or a database or somewhere else?

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear

Comment: ok thanks for the clarifications. The other service can't pick up the information on the fly, do you agree? You need to persist the data in the database for example and make your rest controller get items from the database. Does this make sense?

Comment: Okay. So maybe I can write to a file and pick up the data from a file. Would that be the worst idea?

Comment: You could use files, but  I would recommend using the database instead.

Comment: So I am trying not to have to create an infrastructure for a database. What if I used an in memory database? The data will be deleted after it is processed. Because the other service will be pick it up, process it further and than service it on its database.

Comment: Well, if you want use an in-memory database, then you need to run both the batch job and the rest controller in the same JVM so that both of them can access the data.